# Parabolic PDEs Maximum Principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider diffusion equation for t>0 and $ \boldsymbol{x} $ in a bounded doman $ D$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and a given scalar field $a(\boldsymbol{x}) >0$ that is uniformly bounded and continuously differentiable for all $ \boldsymbol{x} \in \overline{{D}} $.

$$ u_t = \nabla \cdot (a(\boldsymbol{x}) \nabla u) = \sum (a(\boldsymbol{x})u_{x_i})_{x_i}  $$

Suppose u is a solution satisfying the equation in $ D \times[0,T]$.

I know it is true that u has maximum on $D \times (0) \cup \partial D \times[0,T]$, since its similar to the maximaum principle for parabolic PDE but don't see how I can show this.

Comment: The book by Protter and Weinberger, "Maximum Principles in Differential Equations," is excellent.  The rough idea is the same, but there are some rather clever details.  If you knew that any purported maximum really obeyed the second derivative test, and its Hessian was negative definite, then you could see why it is true.  But it might only be negative semi-definite.

Comment: Cheers, I borrowed the book today, took me sometime to find a copy at our local library, going to have a look during the day, hopefully will come up with something.